# How to copy the first word from a column imported from xlsx file to Rstudio and past it on the searchbox of a web page?

Tags: r, excel, copy, xlsx, search-box

I have an excell file with one colomn of words. I want to import these column into R. For this I used:

```
read.xlsx("C:/Users/Sandrine/Desktop/RAHT2_cluster_markers_wilcoxon_test_v7.xlsx", 1, header=TRUE, colClasses=NA)
```

Then in R, I want to copy the first word of the column and past it in the "search Term" box of this website and search the word: https://www.genecards.org/. The website will provide a list of results listed from number 1 to 25: I want to copy whatever is written in the column 2 (called Symbol) and the column 3 (called Description) and past them in the xlsx original file `(RAHT2_cluster_markers_wilcoxon_test_v7.xlsx)` in the same line from which was taken the word (here line 1).

And I want the code to be able to do this for all the words of the column of my xlsx file.

What code should I use to do this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? can you dput() your RAHT2_cluster_markers_wilcoxon_test_v7.xlsx  file ?

Comment: The file can be found here: grosfi.ch/E2vzdepwzar

Comment: I am a total beginner in R, so I was just looking for a code that would do something similar to what I want to start working from it